# Regular expression for: Nested parenthesis with operators

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I am experiencing some problems into building this regular expression, maybe you guys know the right way to do it.

Here I give you some examples of inputs I have:

- `1,(7|8),2,3`
- `1|(2,3)|4`
- `(1,2)|(3|4)`
- `1,(2|(3,4)|(5|6))|8`

I want to be able to convert this into mysql filters while using PHP7. Expected would be:

- 1,(7|8),2,3: `field = 1 and (field = 7 or field = 8) and field = 2 and field = 3`
- 1|(2,3)|4: `field = 1 or (field = 2 and field = 3) or field = 4`
- (1,2)|(3|4): `(field = 1 and field = 2) or (field = 3 and field = 4)`
- 1,(2|(3,4)|(5|6))|8: `field = 1 and (field = 2 or (field = 3 and field = 4) or (field = 5 or field = 6)) or field = 8`

Would be very easly to just replace "," with "AND" and "|" with OR but thats not what I want.
For security reasons I need to validate recursion level and every single value being used but also escape them.

Recursion is needed.

I need advise on how to move forward. I really appreciate some tips.

Thanks a million

Comment: Can you include some of your code so we can see what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

What do you think the word *regular* means in a regular expression?

It means it can match a [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), which is a certain class of languages or grammars. A Computer Science curriculum covers this. It should also be mentioned in a Discrete Mathematics class.

Nested parentheses is the textbook example of a language that regular expressions cannot parse. To parse nested parentheses, you need a recursive-descent parser, or some kind of parser that can keep track of the depth of your parentheses. It can use a counter or a stack to do that, for example.

But a regular expression has no counter variable and has no stack. Therefore it cannot validate a language that has nested structures.